# Selenium Webdriver url related

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium2

I want to open any url in firefox browser but it does not open. what should I do?

I installed firefox 47. I put in my code here.

```
public class Baseclass {
public static WebDriver driver;
public static WebDriver OpenBrowser(){
    String browsername="firefox";
    String url="https://www.healthcarevalunteer.com";
    if(browsername.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")){
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        // Create the Selenium implementation
        Selenium selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, url);

        // Perform actions with selenium
        selenium.open("http://www.google.com");

        driver.get(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not migrating RC tests to WebDriver you don't need the WebDriverBackedSelenium.

This should work as you expect:

```
    final String url = "https://www.healthcarevalunteer.com";
    final RemoteWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get(url);
```